# Preserve the records without value for measure in report

Tags: ssas-tabular

Aim: User wants to see all Auto's irrespective of Premium.

I created a tabular model for Auto Policies. Where an DimAuto is associated with FactPremium. However, there are cases in which an AutoItem Doesn't have a premium associated with it(the key for such AutoItems in FactPremium is 0 so that it can join to dimAuto). When browsing on excel I am not able to see the AutoItems that doesnt have premium associated with it in the Pivot Table.

I would like to know if there is any way to display every auto Items ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, you can set this property in the PivotTable settings (Rows > Field Settings):

[image: Excel]

In PowerBI, this option is also available:

[image: PowerBI]

As alternative, you can adjust the measure, by adding 0 (zero)...

```
Sales plus 0 = SUM(Sales[Sales]) + 0
```

...or correct for blank values:

```
Sales if blank = 
VAR Amount = SUM(Sales[Sales])
RETURN
IF (ISBLANK(Amount);0;Amount)
```

Comment: I know about the Show items with No data option in Excel, but in my case, that option is by default greyed out.. so I am not able to use that.

Comment: Ok, I see. Modify or add the DAX measures, is that an option? More info, same question: https://superuser.com/questions/651102/excel-2010-powerpivot-how-do-i-show-items-with-no-data

Comment: I used the ISBLANK option on all the measures and worked this one out. Thank you for your help.